Failed to connect to PostgreSQL from .NET application when using Docker Compose for FastAPI and PostgreSQL
I have two applications on my local machine: App1 (using FastAPI) and App2 (using .NET). I want both applications to share the same PostgreSQL database.
The PostgreSQL service for App1 is defined in the docker-compose.yml as follows:
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgresssql_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  # Persist PostgreSQL data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin  # Persist pgAdmin data
    depends_on:
      - db

  app:
    container_name: abc-pedia-search
    build: .
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin_data:

In App2 (a .NET Core application), I am trying to connect to the same PostgreSQL database using the following connection string in my appsettings.json:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=AbcPediaDb;Username=postgres;Password=XXXXXX"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

When I try to connect to the database, I get the following error:
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:5432
Here is the part of the .NET code that throws the error:
await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
});

App2's docker-compose.yml looks like this:
version: '3.4'

services:
  oshopedia.online:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}Abcpediaonline
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Abcpedia.online/Dockerfile

It seems like the App2 container is not able to connect to the PostgreSQL service from App1, and I'm not sure how to make them communicate properly.
I verified that PostgreSQL is accessible by connecting through pgAdmin and it works fine.
I've confirmed that App1 is working properly with the database.
Is there any configuration I need to adjust in either App1 or App2's docker-compose.yml or connection strings to allow App2 to connect to the database in App1.

Does Communication between multiple docker-compose projects answer your question?  You need to reconfigure the default network for the app2 Compose file to point at app1's network.  I'd usually recommend using a separate database container per project or service, though; add a second database container to app2/docker-compose.yml.
